# could not find gem 'tenderlove-frex' when installing the gem melomel. where can i find this gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I am trying to install the gem melomel for testing in actionscript. When i require it in my gemfile and bundle update, i get an error saying that it cant find the gem tenderlove-frex and outputs this message:

`Could not find gem 'tenderlove-frex (>= 0) ruby', which is required by gem 'spree (>= 0) ruby', in any of the sources.Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "nokogiri":
  In Gemfile:
    spree (>= 0) ruby depends on
      nokogiri (~> 1.5.0) ruby
    spree (>= 0) ruby depends on
      nokogiri (1.0.0)`

When i remove melomel form my gemfile, bundle updates fine. I have looked all over online and it seems like every location where its been hosted has removed the gem.

Where can I get this gem? i am using ruby 1.9.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `frex` gem is not hosted on the typical Gemcutter.

To get it, add GitHub to your gem sources:

```
gem sources -a http://gems.github.com
```

Then try installing the gem as usual:

```
gem install tenderlove-frex
```

In case it's helpful: tenderlove is the handle of Aaron Patterson, one of the top Ruby developers, and as far as I know he's replaced frex and likely has a better solution you can use. For example, can you update your Nokogiri gem to the current version, and also your Spree gem to the current version? This should remove the need for frex.

To see your versions:

```
$ gem list melomel
melomel (0.6.6)

$ gem list spree
spree (1.2.2)
spree_api (1.2.2)
spree_cmd (1.2.2)
spree_core (1.2.2)
spree_dash (1.2.2)
spree_promo (1.2.2)
spree_sample (1.2.2)
```

To update:

```
$ bundle update
```

To see dependency list for Nokogiri:

```
$ gem dependency nokogiri
```

Comment: this worked for installing tenderlove-frex, thanks. However, I am still getting the previous error with versions of nokogiri. I am using spree 1.1.4 So it is pretty up-to-date. I am not sure where spree's second dependency of needing nokogiri 1.0.0 is coming from? When i comment out "gem melomel" in my gemfile, it bundles fine.

Comment: @Zyren I added more info for you; can you upvote this answer?